# Vba counter for counting the number of goals player has made

Tags: vba, excel

Can i make a macro with vba for counting the number of goals a player makes in season. I already have a working start where the user is first asked the players name where to add goals and then asks the number of goals. But if i add more goals to the same player i want the previous number of goals add to the new number
example player makes 3 goals in the first game and next week he makes 4 goals total player has made 7 
i want the number seven been shown not number 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
Sub maalit()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim strSearch As String
   Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

    Dim etsi As String
    etsi = InputBox("Etsi Jäsen", "maalien lisääminen")   'asks the players name


    If Trim(etsi) <> "" Then
         With Sheets("Data").Range("A:A")
             Set Rng = .Find(What:=etsi, _
                             After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                             LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                             MatchCase:=False)
             If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

    tulos = InputBox("Anna pelaajan maalienmäärä", "maalien lisääminen")
    'Rng.Value = tulos        'asks the number of goals but this is the problem place the bacause it adds them to the wrong column i want them to be in column G
    Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value + tulos


        Else
                MsgBox "Jäsentä ei löytynyt"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Code is based on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157024/vba-code-for-adding-information-to-the-right-place).